# Can't get mutual friend with images of all the users from facebook at same time

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get users mutual friend with image
1) **Name**
2) **Total mutual friend count** 
3) **User_Image**

I am using this Facebook api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{facebook_uid}?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)&access_token={access_Token}
```

And I am getting this result

```
{
   "context": {
      "mutual_friends": {
         "data": [
            {
               "name": "Gaurav Varshney",
               "id": "1919297771636793"
            }
         ],
         "paging": {
            "cursors": {
               "before": "MTkxOTI5Nzc3MTYzNjc5MwZDZD",
               "after": "MTkxOTI5Nzc3MTYzNjc5MwZDZD"
            }
         },
         "summary": {
            "total_count": 1
         }
      },
      "id": "dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQMVZBxLkIzIAZCrsH18MkJldpVQt5FdVkJzXiEz7ulaHNGnyCX0gDZCghaZBZAZB0JQd2wTbPd1SnEfWZC394zYYWfOCmnFHga6LbbnYcHhHPA6F3o4ZD"
   },
   "id": "1744744292507346"
}
```

But I am getting no image of the user

I have look an alternative

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/facebook_uid/picture?type=large
```

Then I get an images but I don't find it suitable because suppose if i get 100 mutual friends so for every friend I need to hit this api for getting image .Can anyone give me a proper solution in which I need to hit one api and I get all the three things name,image,total_mutual_friend count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion) to make nested requests.

```
1234567890?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends{name,picture})
```

But I don’t think you can get the count of mutual friends for those mutual friends that same way. For that, you’ll likely have to query the API for the individual mutual friend again.

Edit: To get larger versions of the profile pictures than the default 50*50px ones, you can use the `type` modifier here as well:

```
1234567890?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends{name,picture.type(large)})
```

Comment: I am getting the image but image size is extra small .How to get large image

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/facebook_uid?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends{name,picture})&access_token=access_token